# NSDateFormatter Twitter JSON Api

Tags: ios, twitter, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to format an NSDate out of a date given by the Twitter api (JSON). I'm using a NSDateFormatter therefore.

```
NSString *dateString = string;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString]; 

    NSLog(@"%@",date);
    return date;
```

But, this returns null. The date the Twitter API is giving me is looking like this: Thu, 19 Jan 2012 07:04:51 +0000.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of "string" here when your code is entered?

Comment: Do you need to take account of the ',' ? Just wondering - I haven't done any testing on your code.

Comment: after testing: you forgot `,`-character in your `dateFormat`. With a comma everything is working fine ;)

Comment: Thank you, but when I try it this way: [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"]; it doesn't work either.

Comment: Already having a solution found: I forgot to set the local:

                [dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

You missed the comma following the day in your format string. Correctly:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
```